How to trigger multibranch jenkisn pipeline through lamda function
I am able to trigger a pipeline job through lamda when i configure my creds and token, but i want to trigger a multibranch pipeline through lamda function. The lamda function will trigger the correct branch job based on the conditions. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Just trigger it the same way you would trigger any other job, what's tripping you up?

the tripping part is that we can post an api request with the job name  but there is no way to pass branch as an option in the api call. On jenkins side i was trying to setup the token in multibranch pipeline to remotely trigger the job but we can't set the token there , we can only set the token for multibranch scan through the plugin . If you have any reference or guidance that would be great

Multibranch pipelines are really more like folders than pipelines, if you want to trigger an individual branch (or whatever ref you happen to have) you need to go a level deeper to the actual jobs. So your url should look something like this:
http://localhost:8080/job/multijob_A/job/master/

